# Price (Numeric value) is not setting in facet Meilisearch

Tags: algolia, instantsearch, meilisearch

I have rangeInput field, which has Min and Max input, where user can add price to search, I have below code for price search.

```
customRangeInput({
  container: document.querySelector('#range-input'),
  attribute: 'price',
  }),
```

and I am adding as facet like below:

```
 curl \
  -X POST 'https://search.example.com/indexes/maps/settings' \
  --data '{
      "searchableAttributes": [ "price" ]
  }' -H "X-Meili-API-Key: xxxxxx"
```

but it says Price is not set as facet. can we not se numeric value in facet?
(Attribute price is not set as facet)
any help would be great.

Thanks
Sanjay

Answer (score 0):

In the current version of MeiliSearch you can perform faceting on attributes that are either String or [String]. The whole core team is currently working on a new search engine that will be released with v0.21.0 and will accept numeric values too :)

Comment: is there any way around for it? @CaroFG, how can I still perform search on this? or is only allowed in algolia?

Comment: Maybe by using [filters](https://docs.meilisearch.com/reference/features/filtering.html) instead of facets, it could work if your dataset is not too big. Otherwise, you would have performance issues…

Comment: and algolia search allowed this facet in number? @CaroFG

Comment: I am not very familiar with Algolia, but I think so, since instant-search is a library created by Algolia

Comment: Also, be careful with your master key :) Anyone can access your instance with it

Comment: would mind giving any example of filter? 
search.addWidgets([
   instantsearch.widgets.configure({
    filters: date_timestamp > ${today}
}),
]);
 I got this, but not sure how to pass variable in it from form. @CaroFG

Comment: is there anyway to work min/max filter in Meilisearch?